# Why does the answer appear under all the questions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form that pops up questions and answers as the user responds to them. Right now, "answer 1" appears at the end of the list of questions:
[image: filled form with "answer 1" at the bottom]

I want it to appear under the checked option:
[image: filled form with "answer 1" immediately following the last checked option]

How can I achieve this?

```js
let questions = [{
    id: "q1",
    terminal: false,
    yes: "q2",
    no: "q5"
  },
  {
    id: "q2",
    terminal: false,
    yes: "q3",
    no: "q5"
  },
  {
    id: "q3",
    terminal: false,
    yes: "q4",
    no: "q4",
    bo: "q4"
  }
];

document.addEventListener("click", processResponse);

function processResponse(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("box")) {
    const
      box = event.target,
      question = box.parentElement,
      response = box.dataset.response,
      boxAndSibling = question.querySelectorAll(".box"),
      sibling = response == "no" ? boxAndSibling[0] : boxAndSibling[1],
      resultDisplay = document.getElementById("result");
    if (!sibling.classList.contains("check-box")) {
      box.classList.toggle("check-box");
      for (let quest of questions) {
        if (quest.id == question.id) {
          if (quest.terminal) {
            result = quest[response];
            resultDisplay.innerHTML = "";
          } else {
            const next = document.getElementById(quest[response]);
            next.classList.toggle("active");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.box::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.check-box::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

#result {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="q1">
  Question number 1</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span>
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>

<div id="q2" class="nested">
  <span>Question number 2</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span>
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>

<div id="q3" class="nested">
  <span>Read:</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">read and click 1</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="no">read and click 2</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="bo">read and click 3</span><br />
</div>

<div id="q4" class="nested">
  <span>answer 1</span><br />
</div>

<div id="q5" class="nested">
  <span>answer 2</span><br />
</div>
```

Comment: please, format your code, it's hard to read...

Comment: ok, I asked the question again and entered the correct code
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let questions = [{
    id: "q1",
    terminal: false,
    yes: "q2",
    no: "q5"
  },
  {
    id: "q2",
    terminal: false,
    yes: "q3",
    no: "q5"
  },
  {
    id: "q3",
    terminal: false,
    yes: "q4",
    no: "q4",
    bo: "q4"
  }
];

document.addEventListener("click", processResponse);

function processResponse(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("box")) {
    const
      box = event.target,
      question = box.parentElement,
      response = box.dataset.response,
      boxAndSibling = question.querySelectorAll(".box"),
      sibling = response == "no" ? boxAndSibling[0] : boxAndSibling[1],
      resultDisplay = document.getElementById("result");
    if (!sibling.classList.contains("check-box")) {
      box.classList.toggle("check-box");
      for (let quest of questions) {
        if (quest.id == question.id) {
          if (quest.terminal) {
            result = quest[response];
            resultDisplay.innerHTML = "";
          } else {
            const next = document.getElementById(quest[response]);
            next.classList.toggle("active");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.box::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.check-box::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

#result {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="q1">
  Question number 1</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span>
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>

<div id="q2" class="nested">
  <span>Question number 2</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">Yes</span>
  <span class="box" data-response="no">No</span><br />
</div>

<div id="q3" class="nested">
  <span>Read:</span><br />
  <span class="box" data-response="yes">read and click 1</span><br />
<div id="q4" class="nested">
  <span>answer 1</span><br />
</div>
  <span class="box" data-response="no">read and click 2</span><br />
<div id="q5" class="nested">
  <span>answer 2</span><br />
</div>
  <span class="box" data-response="bo">read and click 3</span><br />
</div>
```